# Is there anyway to stop the flow of events in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, events

that is a question I have been asking myself for a while.

Giving a certain flow of events, can I when handling one of them, **stop the next ones to be raised**?

For example, when collapsing a node which child was selected in a **treeview** (winform), the events are raised like that:

- BeforeCollapse
- BeforeSelect
- AfterSelect
- AfterCollapse

I could stop them by using a class member, but I was wondering whether there was a built-in function or just another way (a more elegant way) to achieve this, by acting directly on the events queue.

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe thats what they call as Custom Control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily, no. The order of the events firing is controlled by the TreeView control class, and there is no built-in way to prevent events from firing. But you have a couple of options:

1. Create your own TreeView class that inherits from the base class,
   then add a `bool` property to prevent the events from processing.
   Then you can override `BeforeCollapse`, etc. to check the bool
   before calling `base.BeforeCollapse`.
2. Just create a `bool` flag, and check the flag in each of the events.

Comment: Ok, I think they should add this functionnality in the .NET 5 framework, cause it is not the first time I am willing to do something like that

Comment: I'm not sure they are going to invest that much in WinForms anymore. They are more likely to focus on WPF and WinRT for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to do that for *that* type of event (you are asking for TreeView).

Like for example could be managed [KeyEventArgs.Handled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.handled.aspx) via built-in mechanism.

You can use some instance (boolean ?) value to manage the flow,

or you can, *unsubscribe* from the event that you don't want more recieve, but after subscribe to it again. Sounds rough solution, but sometimes turns out reasonable one.

Comment: I can't access the events of the control to unsuscribe them, I guess it is because they are built-in events. Thx for answering

Comment: @GianT971: in this case manage it with you own "switch" variable.

Comment: Yeah, it will be simpler and faster than creating a custom control

Answer (score 0):

even if the event are raised nothing will happen if you don't bind an event handler to them. In this case you can just remove the handler using the code below:

```
object.Event -= new EventHandlerType(your_Method)
```

Otherwise you should create your own custom control

Comment: Ok, but I can access no Event property in this control

Comment: you have to create your own custom control in this case. But if there is not a handler for an event why do you need to prevent it to be raised?

Comment: I meant that typing MyTreeview.Event will result in an error. The same goes for MyTreeview.BeforeCollapse.

Comment: you have to create your custom control then

Answer (score 0):

according to [OnBeforeCollapse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.onbeforecollapse.aspx) you get an [TreeViewCancelEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.treeviewcanceleventargs) which has an `Cancel` property. Setting this to true should stop the flow, but will also not collapse it.
Same goes for `OnBeforeSelect`.

Answer (score 0):

The only times you can easily "cancel" an event is if the event handler has the `CancelEventHandler` delegate type.  Even then it doesn't really cancel it as much as set a flag for the remaining events that makes it skip performing all the events subscribed to it.

If you *did* have a `CancelEventHandler` type (which these don't) you'd simply set `Cancel` to true on the event object itself in the handler.

Plenty of other answers give you suggestions for what you should o.  I'd just go with your idea: set a 'event cancelled' flag in your control class, and check it.  When the last event in the series gets called, reset it.